# How to mute someone?

Tags: lync

Every morning Alice and I have a Lync conference call with Bob and Charlie from the other office. I sit next to Alice, so when she speaks, I can hear her twice—through the air and with a delay through the headphones. This is aurally annoying. I could take the headphones off, but then I can't hear Bob's interjections. How can I mute just Alice so I can't hear her through the headphones?

Comment: Easy solution - use this to justify working remotely.

Comment: When the voice from Alice come to you through the headphone, it is not just Alice's voice. It is actually the sound from the meeting itself. You are connected directly to a meeting server and the meeting server sends you a voice stream that has all the voices mixed. It is similar to having a meeting over a traditional phone line with Bob, Charlie and Alice all sitting in a meeting room and you want to mute Alice while hearing Bob and Charlie.

Comment: @someuser thanks for explaining, that's helpful to understand

Comment: TeamSpeak and Mumble can do this.

Comment: I have a truly low-tech, $0 suggestion. You could simply go together with Alice into a conference room...

Comment: @Fritz Lync is *enterprise software* "Skype for Business"! Gamers have to use free open-source apps because they need the better features and greater reliability.

Answer (score 2):

So far as I can tell, the only mute option built into Lync is of the presenter to mute someone entirely such that nobody on the conference can hear them.

There are some hardware solutions including noise-canceling phone headsets that I just found out existed thanks to [Google](http://www.headsets.com/corded/headset/mic/noise-canceling) and [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/gp/search/ref=sr_nr_n_4?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A229193%2Ck%3Anoise-canceling%20phone%20headset&keywords=noise-canceling%20phone%20headset&ie=UTF8&qid=1435066408&rnid=2941120011). You could look for one that fits your needs.

There may also be some non-Lync software solutions but I don't know of them.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

As a participant, it appears there is no way to mute another participant:

[Technet Lync Forums](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/80511aa3-b9be-48bc-bdda-34abe307e46a/can-a-participant-not-leader-mute-a-single-participant-in-conference-call?forum=ocsconferencing)

From the presenter's perspective, it can be done.

[Mute-or-unmute-audio-in-a-Skype-for-Business-Lync-Meeting-or-call](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Mute-or-unmute-audio-in-a-Skype-for-Business-Lync-Meeting-or-call-94f12302-dc95-44ba-8792-c43e115b3d26?ui=en-US&rs=en-NZ&ad=NZ)

> Mute or unmute the audience in a Skype for Business (Lync) Meeting
>   To mute individuals, point to the people button in the meeting. Then right-click a participant and click Mute. ... To mute the entire audience, point to the people button in the meeting. Then select the ACTIONS tab and click Mute Audience.

Comment: This action is only available to the presenter and it mutes Alice for *everyone*. I think OP wants everybody else to hear Alice and have her only muted in OP's headphones.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to mute the voice of Alice coming from the conference call, why not mute Alice's original voice? You have two options here:

1. Go sit somewhere else during the conference call
2. Buy yourself [hearing protection headphones](https://www.google.de/search?q=safety+headphones), like these:
   [image]

These have the added benefit of dealing with other disturbing noises, like people talking nearby while you're in a conference.